# Remove empty string in array of strings

Tags: php, arrays, csv

It seems that there are dozens of topic with similar problem, and mostly all have the same answer: use `array_filter`, `array_map`. The problem is that I used them, but it didn't quite help. So I have an array (is built from data in csv file):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => name
        [1] => title
        [2] => email
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => First
        [1] => title 1
        [2] => email1@ex.com
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => second
        [1] => title 1
        [2] => email2@ex.com
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => third
        [1] => title 1
        [2] => email3@ex.com
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] =>  
        [2] => 
    ) 
 )
```

I have to delete all empty arrays. So I use such code:

```
    while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 8192, ';')) !== false) {
        if (array(null) !== $row) { // ignore blank lines
            $csv[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $array = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $csv));
```

$array now is:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => name
        [1] => title
        [2] => email
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => First
        [1] => title 1
        [2] => email1@ex.com
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => second
        [1] => title 1
        [2] => email2@ex.com
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => third
        [1] => title 1
        [2] => email3@ex.com
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [1] =>  
    )
)
```

Why there is a 4th array with empty value? I need to get rid of it.
`gettype($array[4][1])`  = string

UPDATE

The csv has empty rows, and even just a ";" delimiter without any string. I cannot influence on the process of inserting data into this csv.
The csv looks like this:

```
 1 row: name;title;email
 2 row: First;title 1;email1@ex.com
 3 row: second;title 1;email2@ex.com
 4 row:
 5 row: third;title 1;email3@ex.com
 6 row:
 7 row: ; ;
```

Comment: It looks like the element in [6][1] as some whitespace in it.

Comment: you are right guys. There are empty rows. I will Update post with csv data, so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and mostly all have the same answer: use array_filter, array_map.

array_filter is a good approach, but I wouldn't use array_map, but array_reduce:

```php
$array = array_filter(
    $csv,
    function ($value) {
        return 0 < array_reduce(
            $value,
            function ($carry, $item) {
                return empty(trim($item)) ? $carry : $carry + 1;
            },
            0
        );
    }
);
```

With array_reduce, I count the non-empty elements in an array. And if there are zero non-empty elements, the array is thrown away with array_filter.

For reference, the PHP 7.4-syntax, which looks nicer in my eyes, but could be a bit confusing at first

```php
$array = array_filter(
    $csv,
    fn ($val) => 0 < array_reduce(
        $val, 
        fn ($carry, $item) => empty(trim($item)) ? $carry : $carry + 1, 
        0
    )
);
```

Comment: Well, that is new for me. That worked perfectly! Thank you for not only the solution, but also for the explanation. Very helpful!

Comment: Just a quick question: what stands second `0` for by PHP 7.4-syntax?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot it in the first one. It's the default parameter for the `$carry`. Have a look here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php